# PHP Recursive JSON Children Search

Tags: php, loops, recursion, logic

I need to parse JSON which looks like this:

```
{
    "mdfId":"282088127",
    "mdfConcept":"ME 3400EG-12CS-M Switch",
    "children":[
        {
            "mdfId":"007",
            "mdfConcept":"Another item",
            "children": [
                // many more here
            ]
        },
        {
             "mdfId":"008",
             "mdfConcept":"Another one",
             "children": [
                 {
                     "mdfId":"010",
                     "mdfConcept":"What I'm looking for!",
                     "children": [] // no children
                 }
             ]
        },
        // many more here
    ]
},
```

This is a recursive structure in which every element has `mdfId`, `mdfConcept` and `children` keys.

Say I need to find node with `ID=010` within this structure. I don't know at which level it lies (e.g. it can be on top level, or several `children` nodes below).

My current approach is:

```
$mdfId = '010'; // what I'm loking for

foreach ($jsonResponse as $category) {
    while (true) {
        if ($category['mdfId'] == $mdfId) {
            // we found it!
            $categoryDevices[$mdfId] = $category['children'];
            break 2;
        }

        if (!empty($category['children'])) {
            next_cat:

            if (is_null($category['children'])) {
                break;
            }

            $category = array_shift($category['children']);
            continue;
        }

        if (empty($category['children'])) {
            goto next_cat;
        }
    }
}
```

But current approach misses some cases. How can I optimize this recursive loop so it checks all nodes on same level and each one accesible through any number of `children` keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically I wrote a function that didn't return anything, but rather populated a variable from arguments.

```
function findRecursiveArrayNodeById($id, $array, &$node) {
    foreach ($array as $child) {
        if (isset($child['mdfId']) && $child['mdfId'] == $id) {
            $node = $child;
            return;
        }

        if (!empty($child['children'])) {
            findRecursiveArrayNodeById($id, $child['children'], $node);
        }
    }
}
```

Usage as follows:

```
$result = false;

findRecursiveArrayNodeById($mdfId, $category_json, $result);

if (!$result) {
    println("did not find {$mdfId}");
    continue;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

An embarrassing feature of your JSON object is that, while each `children` member is an array of the "child" structure, *the top level one is the object itself*, so it's an obstacle to a *really recursive* approach.

We might workaround by turning the source JSON object into the same structure as nested levels, i.e.:

- having `$jsonResponse` as original object
- use `['children' => $jsonResponse]` instead

This way, it should work with something like this:

```
$mdfId = '010'; // what I'm loking for

if ($result = look4id(['children' => $jsonResponse], $mdfId) {
    $categoryDevices[$mdfId] = $result;
}

function look4id($source, $id) {
    foreach ($source as $child) {
        if ($child['mdfId'] == $id) {
            return $source['children'];
        } else {
            if ($source['children']) {
                return look4id($source['children'], $id);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Overall good answer and approach. Allowed me to increase findings rate from 30% to 60%. However once the loop goes into several `children` deep, it forgets about untouched elements on higher levels. So if `007` and `008` were placed in reverse order, script would have checked `008` and its child `010` but totally missed `007`.

Comment: @DenisBobrovnikov Hum... interesting issue! Could you post an example of a JSON object and which key is not found, if not too heavy? (you might edit your OP and put the object in a SO snippet)